# Why bitwise OR and AND logic is not working as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, bitwise-operators

I have the below sample code. I was always under the impression that doing Bitwise OR on enum values, will allow me to check the result (using Bitwise AND) to see which enum values are included in the result and which are not.

For example, if I do `result = mouse | headphone`, then I can check agaist `result & mouse == mouse` as condition to know if `mouse` is included in `result` or not. But it seem that whatever I `&` result with, say X, I always end up with X. Why?

In the below code, I thought that the if should fail since `straw` was not included in `options`, but it does not..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

enum Stock  
{
    milk,
    choclate,
    tv,
    cable,
    mouse,
    fan,
    headphone,
    cup,
    straw,
    pen,
    candy,
    glasses,
    book,
    plug

};


int main()
{
    Stock options = static_cast<Stock>( static_cast<int>(mouse) | static_cast<int>(headphone)
                                            | static_cast<int>(cup) | static_cast<int>(pen)     );

    if ((static_cast<int>(loptions)) & (static_cast<int>(straw)) == static_cast<int>(straw))
    {
        cout << "bring straw!" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Even when I add unique-bit set for the enum values, it does not work. For the below code, it ignores both if() statements when I am expecting it to display `"bring cup"` instead:

```
enum Stock
{
    milk = 1,
    choclate = 2,
    tv = 4,
    cable = 8,
    mouse = 16,
    fan = 32,
    headphone = 64,
    cup = 128,
    straw = 256,
    pen = 512,
    candy = 1024,
    glasses = 2048,
    book = 4096,
    plug = 8192

};


int main()
{
    Stock options = static_cast<Stock>(static_cast<int>(mouse) | static_cast<int>(headphone)
                                        | static_cast<int>(cup) | static_cast<int>(pen));

    if ((static_cast<int>(options)) & (static_cast<int>(straw)) == static_cast<int>(straw))
    {
        cout << "bring straw!" << endl;
    }

    if ((static_cast<int>(options)) & (static_cast<int>(cup)) == static_cast<int>(cup))
    {
        cout << "bring cup!" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assuming each `enum`'s value is a unique bit. That's not the case. `enum`s values are always 1 higher than the previous enum value, unless otherwise provided.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But are not enum values unique already? 1 higher than the previous, makes it unique in the set, no?

Comment: @LambaDawet Yeah, but unique value does not mean unique distinct bit. Unique bits would mean the values 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. need to be used instead. Here for example `cable == tv | chocolate`. `milk` is zero and doesn't even have any bits at 1. Maybe you are confused about how binary AND and OR operators work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `unique value does not mean unique bit` ha? Can you please clarify more with an overview/example/answer

Comment: To do bitwise checking, shouldn't the different parameters to be OR'ed together (and checked for with AND's) all be powers of 2 (i.e. 1,2,4,8,...), instead of being a linear range 0,1,2,3,4,5? (in line with @FrançoisAndrieux 's comment)

Comment: try this for distinct bits https://godbolt.org/z/4V5Xee

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah... I see. I guess doing: `milk = 1,
 choclate = 2,
 tv = 4,
 cable = 8,
 mouse = 16, etc..` Will make it work. Pretty cool! Thanks

Comment: @Oblivion Well, except that `pen == candy` in your example.

Comment: @LambaDawet Yes.

Comment: Did you do any research?  Please review "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum"  ... which contains the example "enum Foo { a, b, c = 10, d, e = 1, f, g = f + c };" defining the values as
 " //a = 0, b = 1, c = 10, d = 11, e = 1, f = 2, g = 12 "  Clearly not single bit values.

Comment: Your edit has the parentheses placed wrong.  It is sufficient to write `if ((options & cup) == cup)`, the `static_cast`s are useless.  But it IS important to do `(options & cup) == cup` and not `options & (cup == cup)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use enums as bitsets (or flags) you need to make sure the binary representation for each enum value contains exactly one bit set to 1. In other words, each enum value needs to be a power of two. Example :

```
enum Stock  
{
    milk = 1,     // 0b0001
    choclate = 2, // 0b0010
    tv = 4,       // 0b0100
    cable = 8     // 0b1000
    // etc.
};
```

Otherwise, bit-wise logical operators won't be able to differentiate between certain values and certain combinations of other values. In the original code `chocolate`, `tv` and `cable` have the values `1`, `2` and `3` respectively. In binary, that is `01`, `10` and `11`. ORing `chocolate` and `tv` produces `11` (`0b01 | 0b10 == 0b11`) which is the same value as `cable`. The combination of the `chocolate` and `tv` is not distinguishable from the `cable` flag.

But c++ provides [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). This class allows you to easily manipulate a bit set in a way similar to an array of bits. You can then just use your original enum and use each enum value as the *index* of a bit.

Comment: I added the values like you did, and if I do `if( for the cup )` like i do for the `straw`, it ignores both statements and does not display anything. Can you please check?

Comment: @LambaDawet I get a "'&': check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence" warning when I try your code. The `==` happens before the `&`. You can use parentheses around the left side of the equation to fix this. But an easier solution would be to remove the equality completely. Just `x & y` will yield true if `x` has any of the bits in common with `y`. No need to compare with `y`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!

Comment: "ORing chocolate and tv produces 11 (0b01 | 0b10 == 0b11) which is the same value as cable." - That's false!

Comment: @Ajay Care to elaborate?

Comment: Cable's value is not 0b11, but 0b1000, ORing chocolate and TV doesn't produce it. Also, in the comments, you are using Hex format, which is also incorrect. In short, 2|4 != 8

Comment: @Ajay You may have missed *"For example, consider the original code."*. That part of the answer refers to the original question where `cable`'s value is in fact 3. You are right about the comments. Edit : Maybe the edit makes it more clear.

Comment: A nicer way to get those values IMO is to declare them as `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, `1 << 2`, etc.